# MongoDB: Updating Within Nested Array

Tags: mongodb

I have a beautiful little MongoDB collection with the following object:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5919df60adb8170833fb4fa9"),
  "a" : [
    {
      "_id" : ObjectId("5919df60adb8170833fb4faa"),
      "b" : {
        "c" : true,
        "d" : [
          {
            "e" : "cats",
          },
          {
            "f" : "dogs",
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

One can set this up by running `mongo` then running the following commands:

```
use cats
db.wonk.insertOne({"_id":ObjectId("5919df60adb8170833fb4fa9"),"a":[{"_id":ObjectId("5919df60adb8170833fb4faa"),"b":{"c":true,"d":[{"e":"cats",},{"f":"dogs",}]}}]})
```

I want to set the value of ‘e’ to ‘meow’, but can’t figure out how to query up that object. I thought the following would find e but no dice:

```
db.wonk.find({a: {  $elemMatch: { 'b': { 'd': { $elemMatch: { 'e': 'cats'  }  }  }  }  }})
```

My question is: how can I set the value of `e` to `meow`? Any help others can offer on this question would be hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [positional filtered operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/index.html) here:

```
db.wonk.update({ "_id":ObjectId("5919df60adb8170833fb4fa9") }, 
    { $set: { "a.$[doc1].b.d.$[doc2].e": "meow" } }, 
    { arrayFilters: [ { "doc1._id": ObjectId("5919df60adb8170833fb4faa")  }, { "doc2.e": "cats" } ] })
```

`doc1` and `doc2` are simply kind of placeholders that can be then used inside `arrayFilters` to define conditions that are used by MongoDB when traversing your document.

Comment: Thanks @mickl! Was arrayFilters deprecated in recent MongoDB? I have 4.0.3 and that gives me `WriteCommandError({"ok":0,"errmsg":"Unrecognizedfieldinupdateoperation:arrayFilters","code":9,"codeName":"FailedToParse"})`

Comment: That's weird. I've tried on 4.0.0 and works fine, moreover this example follows the documentation. What MongoDB driver are you using ?

Comment: Well I decided not to go down that rabbit hole--I installed 3.6 with `brew install mongodb@3.6`, restarted the service, and updated the featureCompatibilityVersion to 3.6 with `db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "3.6" } )` then could run your command perfectly. Thanks again for your help with this!